# Assigning function to var does not work. Value is still 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, graph

I'm struggling with this problem since a while.
I'm new in **Javascript**, so there are some things I still don't understand. 
I created function **linkBuilder** to extract some data from a JSON file. I tested **parseLine** and it works.

```
links=[];
let linkBuilder = function(){
  d3.text('prova2utenti.json',function(err,data){
  if (err) throw err;
  var elements = data.split('\n');
  for (var i=0, l=elements.length; i<l; i++){
    links.concat(parseLine(elements[i]));
    console.log(links);
  }
  });
}
```

The ***Problem*** is that when I try to create the links for my graph using this code:

```
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});
```

Nothing is shown on my web page, it is like the var *links* is never initialized. I suppose this is because of the **hoisting**, but I'm not sure and anyway I don't know how to solve.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: When and how does the `linkBuilder` function get called?

Comment: "_like the var links is never initialized_" It isn't, how many times you think `forEach` will loop an empty array ..? + `link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});` doesn't do what you think it does, rather it's a syntax error.

Comment: Besides the fact that you are not calling `linkBuilder`, where is this `forEach`? Inside or outside `d3.text`? A hint: it **cannot** be outside.

Comment: @JasonSmith I call `linkBuilder` after some functions, doing just `linkBuilder()`. 
@GerardoFurtado Actually the `forEach` is **outside** the `d3.text`.
Is this the right manner to call the function? How should I modify the d3.text to not let the `var links` be empty?

Comment: @bumbum `d3.text` is **asynchronous**. You have to put the `forEach` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I was able to solve this issue. Like @GerardoFurtado suggested, I put all the logic to draw graph in a **dedicated** function. Then simply call that function inside the `d3.text` and that does the work. 
I had **another issue** with the `concat()` function. It creates a **new array** each time is called instead of adding to the same. I solved using `push()` method.